# C# WPF - Datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

How can we achieve this type of datagrid with editable combobox, searching on multiple columns?[Advanced Datagrid Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GFfMP.png)

Answer (score 0):

That is probably some custom control?
DevExpress offers this features with their WPF Controls.